# how to: question mark in form action

Tags: html, forms, url, button

I want to use a button to link to a page. However, the page url is something like domain.com/page?action=register.

I really need this action added to my:

```
form action="domain.com/page?action=register"
```

Form attribute, but when I try it with these settings, it will only go to domain.com/page

I've tried encoding the `?` into `%3F` but that doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Could you provide us with a link to the actual site and/or a bit more code? :-)

Comment: Are you using `get` or `post`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ? values are set by the form, as long as the form's method is set to "get" (rather than "post", which doesn't submit the values in the URL). So, if you want to submit a form to page?action=register, you'd do the following:

```
 <form action="domain.com/page" method="get">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register">
```

It will *also* pass the other form values along in the URL, creating something like:

```
domain.com/page?action=register&first_name=john&last_name=doe
```

EDIT: As @ninetwozero mentioned in a comment, the scenario you describe above *should* work:

```
<form action="domain.com/page?action=register" method="post">
[rest of form]
```

I just tested the above and it passed both the `?action=register` and the form values from my form. So, whichever you prefer.

Comment: He could however also POST to the `page?action=register`, keeping the url intact and not cramming it with all the form values. Both ways would work though, just thought I'd mention it. :-)

Comment: Excellent point. I assumed it wouldn't work based on the described problem, but you're absolutely right. Thanks!

Comment: That's an excellent answer. I've chosen the method=post option, since it's the most compact one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is "domain.com/page" the page that has the form and button?

Make sure that your button is like this:

```
<input type="submit" />
```

Not

```
<input type="button" />
```

Otherwise, you could actually use input type "button" with a javascript redirect.

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href="domain.com/page?action=register" />
```

In fact, why use a bunch of form elements if all you want is a button to send you to another url?

```
<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.href="domain.com/page?action=register" />
</form>
```

Not sure if you even need the  tags really. Try it.